# Add offset to numbers in a multiline string

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl I am trying to add an offset to numbers within a string of words in lines. For example:

```
ABC10XYZ8 ( 50  100)
ABC11XYZ8 ( 150 200)
ABC12XYZ8 ( 150 300)
```

I need to change it to

```
ABC20XYZ8 ( 150 150)
ABC21XYZ8 ( 250 250)
ABC22XYZ8 ( 250 350)
```

Basically, add offset of say 10, 100, 50 to those key places.

Somehow, I cant get it to evaluate.

Comment: I am trying to do something like 's/(?<=\ABC)([0-9]+)/10+$1/g'     (Not an expert in perl, i am in medical major trying to get something done quickly)

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your post to include that regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. You're missing the `e` flag for the substitution which evaluates the replacement string as an expression. Also, `\A` in your lookbehind doesn't make sense--you probably want the literal `A` here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "ABC10XYZ8 ( 50  100)
ABC11XYZ8 ( 150 200)
ABC12XYZ8 ( 150 300)";
$str =~ s/(?<=ABC)([0-9]+)/10+$1/ge;
$str =~ s/(?<=\( )([0-9]+)/100+$1/ge;
$str =~ s/([0-9]+)(?=\))/50+$1/ge;
print $str;
```

Output:

```
ABC20XYZ8 ( 150  150)
ABC21XYZ8 ( 250 250)
ABC22XYZ8 ( 250 350)
```

Of course, if you have a lot of these little patterns, you'll probably want to make an array of pairs and write a loop, or create a subroutine abstraction of some sort.

Comment: Note also that the above code doesn't handle the fact that `50 -> 150` now takes an extra space. I'm not sure how much this matters or how large these numbers might get. For example, if one column gets +10000, should you pad out all other rows to match the added width? It's unclear at present but I'm happy to add this code if there's a spec.

Comment: thanks ggorlen. I understand the e flag now also see how you used ?<= and ?=

Comment: Thanks, I now understand ?<= and ?= <br/> i have a concern now if i have multiple matches for "ABC" like ABC10XYZ8ABC50 but want to selective add offset to 1st or 2nd or nth.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that you might have such strings, so you'll need to adapt the regex to match your spec. Maybe work line by line and collect the matches into an array, then you can operate as you see fit on whichever index you need.